# Using jquery ui sortable for merging two ordered list of items into third

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Having two lists`[A,B,C,D]` and `[1,2,3,4]`, I want to provide a user interface for merging them into a new list. In the new list the original order of each list should be maintained. For example any of `[A,1,B,2,C,3,D,4]`or `[A,B,C,D,1,2,3,4]`or `[A,B,1,C,2,3,4,D]`are OK. But `[B,A,1,2,3,4,C,D]` is not accepted, due to `B` coming before `A`.

jQuery UI sortable seems to be a good starting point. But maintaining the original order is not supported (Of course the meaning of sortable is in contrast with my requirement. But the user interface supported with sortable, is very similar to my final goal.)

I think handling receive event and canceling the sort when the order is not maintained, could be the solution. But could not found how to cancel or undo the drag, when receive is complete.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right. jquery's sortable will do the trick.

start with using a helper

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ helper: 'clone' });
```

this won't drag the item itself but a cloned replica.

next you can use the event "beforeStop" to check the previous and next item.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({ 
     helper: 'clone',
     beforeStop: function(event, ui) { ... }
 });
```

remember that the appendTo and prependTo and insertAfter and insertBefore function are moving a dom element rather than cloning it. This means this code is valid for playing with the li elements.

html:

```
<ul>
<li class='i-1'>first</li>
<li class='i-2'>second</li>
<li class='i-3'>third</li>
<li class='i-4'>fourth</li>
</ul>
```

jquery:

```
$('li').eq(3).insertBefore('li.i-1');
```

result:

```
<ul>
<li class='i-4'>fourth</li>
<li class='i-1'>first</li>
<li class='i-2'>second</li>
<li class='i-3'>third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to use the "clone" helper?

Comment: as it doesn't yank the original li from its position

Answer (score 0):

To cancel sorting just return false in sortbeforestop callback:

```
$( "#sortable" ).bind( "sortbeforestop", function(event, ui) {
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually - without going into implementation details and assuming that we're dealing with two arrays of objects - i would first go through each list and adding an incremented property named "OrderPosition" starting at 1 to each object resulting in the following:

```
                item.OrderPosition   
list1item1      1
list1item2      2
list1item3      3

list2item1      4
list2item2      5
```

Then merge the lists with a simple jquery array.merge() which will append array2 to array1 or if you want them merged in an alternating fashion iterate and merge manually. Both methods should preserve the individual lists orders. That should give you the following list when using the second method:

```
                OrderPosition
list1item1      1
list2item1      4
list1item2      2
list2item2      5
list1item3      3
```

This will allow you to maintain knowledge about how low an item may be sorted within the merged lists (an item may not be ordered any lower than the item which has an OrderPosition of draggedItem.OrderPosition+1)

Elements in a jquery sortable control are individual objects of the type draggable. Draggables may be constrained in their movement by the containment option. I would use this to not allow dragging any further than the item before the item with the OrderPosition of draggedItem.OrderPosition+1. Of course you will have to recalculate and reset the settings for containment each time the list order is changed. The advantage of this approach is less frustration for the user because his "work" is not reset each time he orders something in a illegal fashion, the sortable will simply not allow for sorting somethin incorrectly.

Hope this makes any sense or even helps.

Comment: Thanks Till, but I think using containment would cause unnecessary complication.